# Test-Flight App beta testing time limitations

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, testflight

I need to submit my binary files over the air without pushing app to app-store.
one solution is using enterprise program, **Test-Flight App Beta Testing** we can send binary files to external users to limit of 1000.

My Questions is :

1. will apple take beta review (following apple guidelines) of the app?
2. only iOS8 build will be supported?
3. Is there any time limitations for the app in beta phase and then apple will revoke the app?because we are not submitting app to app store.

Is there any alternative SDK's through over the air so that we can send binary files to external users?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can always use Crashlytics by Fabric now. It is super easy to integrate into your code. Check it out at fabric.io

Comment: With TestFlight, currently, each binary can be downloaded for 30days, but once downloaded they continue to run indefinitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test-Flight App Beta Testing**

**Answer 1** : yes, Apps may only use TestFlight to beta test apps intended for public distribution and must comply with the full App Review Guidelines.

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

[image]

**Answer 2** : yes, there won't be any problem if you selected minimum target as iOS 8. If the user has an iOS version lower than iOS 8 then he/she won't be allowed to install the app. This is the default nature of apple.

**Answer 3** : once your application cleared Beta test phase of apple, then apple will allow you to give that build to external testers for 30 days. After 30 days, you need to submit new apps if you want to give a build to external testers. There won't be any way to directly publish an app to the app store once apps that cleared beta test are reviewed. You need to submit as new for publishing the app to the app store.

[BetaTestingTheApp](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 2):

**FYI (as of Jan 2018)** ([TestFlight link](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdc42b26b8))

**Beta App Review** is required for builds tested by external testers.

External testers limit: **10,000** (through invitation by e-mail)

Expiration of beta apps: **90 days**

Hope, it might help someone out there.